# Maxima/Minima question seems contradictory

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Sorry for putting in the picture.I tried but I wasn't able to input the inverse function using Latex.

So my question is as given in no. 21.
It states that, the function is minimum at $\ x=1$.This should mean that $\ f'(x)$ is $0$  at $x=1$. But that is not what I get after differentiating the function.It seems contradictory.

Am I wrong or is the question incorrect?

[image]

Comment: The function need not be continuous. Then the point of discontinuity becomes another critical point.

Comment: So are you saying that we don't always need to have $f'(x)=0$ in order to have a maxima/minima?

Comment: No, for example $f(x)=|x|$, in which case the function is continuous but not differentiable. We have a minima at $x=0$ but the derivative does not exist. On approaching from the positive direction it is $1$, and from the negative it is $-1$.

Comment: So in order to have a maxima/minima at a point I should have either $f'(x)=0$ or $f(x) = 0$ is undefined at that point ? Is that all? I would really like to know more.

Comment: You need to check: 1)points where $f'(x)=0$ 2)points where $f'(x)$ doesn't exist 3)end points of the domain. These are the possible candidates for an extremum.